# Sony vaio laptop's battery never charges to 100%

Tags: battery

I bought a brand new sony vaio laptop (Model E15135). All is good, but its battery never charges to 100%. When it reaches to 99%, and i point the mouse to the battery, it shows "99% Available (Plugged in, Charging)". When i contacted to sony vaio care for warranty, they are saying that there is not such type of issue and we cant do anything for this. Can you please give me any solution?

Comment: Are you using the laptop while it's charging? If so stop and check after a while. Also many devices fast charge initially to a set percentage, then switch to trickle charge the rest of the way that can take much longer. Further, many laptops have restrictions on the max charge percentage, although that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows “Charging”, it means that it is still charging. If it shows that for a long time on 99%, it means most likely that the battery is miscalibrated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the amber battery charge light lit when it is at 99%? It should be.

If not you may have a problem that should be able to be solved:

- If the light is lit and the computer is on AC power, disconnect the power harness pin from the side of the computer.
- Let the computer drain about 5% of the charge... say down to about 92%... then plug the AC pin back into the computer.
- The computer just might complete the charge to 100% and the light will turn off.

It's a very simple approach and may work very well. Good luck!